# Как обратиться через css к созданному мною атрибуту у тега?

Tags: jquery-validation

Хочу изменить цвет обратившись к атрибуту **data-validation-error-msg-required**.

К примеру имеет вот такой код:

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <p>
         <label for="fname">Ваше имя<span class="asteric">*</span></label>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="Введите имя" required="required" data-validation="required alphanumeric" data-validation-error-msg-required="Введи что-то">
       </p>
    </div>
```

не хочу менять исходник, а лишь переписать его свойм .css файлом.

```
.data-validation-error-msg-required - //не работает 
 #data-validation-error-msg-required - //не работает
```

использовал bootstrap и jquery-validator

Answer (score 0):

```css
[data-validation-error-msg-required] {
border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <p>
         <label for="fname">Ваше имя<span class="asteric">*</span></label>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="Введите имя" required="required" data-validation="required alphanumeric" data-validation-error-msg-required="Введи что-то">
       </p>
    </div>
```

используйте квадратные скобки они предназначены для выбора атрибутов:
[data-validation-error-msg-required]

Comment: К сожалению не решилось таким образом.
Решил так задачу:
.has-error .help-block{
    font-size:13px;
}

Comment: ну вы же выполнили мой код? всё получается если вам нужно чтобы отслеживалось конкретное значение надо делать так; [data-validation-error-msg-required="какое то значение"]

Comment: да, безусловно. ток не совсем понял почему он не цепляет его.

Comment: судя по вашему сss .has-error .help-block{ font-size:13px; } вы вообще не туда обращаетесь